# How to Scroll Smoothly as given in this link https://boy-coy.com/#home

Tags: html, css, scroll, frontend, web-developer-toolbar

I want to know how can i make my website scroll smoothly like this one.
https://boy-coy.com/#home
. I've also added parallax effect but they are too fast and scrolling speed too.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the css property `scroll-behavior` with `smooth` value on the element where you want it to scroll *smoothly*